# Sort data with a function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I imported a table from a database and I would like to sort the data with a function so that I can use other formulas.

I tried `VLOOKUP()` but it seems like that is not what is needed.

I don't want to use the sort and filter tools in Excel because I would like it to be dependent on a cell.

For example, I only want to extract the `Client ID` with a value of `20`.

[image: Screenshot of worksheet]

Comment: Have you tried using a pivot table?

Comment: Why would you not want to use the Sort and Filter tools? That would do exactly what you need.

Comment: What do you mean by " I would like it to be dependent on a cell."? Could you show how the result should be based on your example?

Comment: How do you want to get the result? Based on another WorkSheet with the cell value as 20? Please provide more information about your problem.

Comment: What do you want to achieve when you have sorted it? Excel has many functions that could be possible candidates, including `SUMIF`, `SUMPRODUCT` or `VLOOKUP`. Without knowing what you want to achieve, we can't help.